# Recording the online meetings

Tags: meetings, clients, consulting, consultants

I often take online meetings with my clients to provide them technical consultation. They’re all audio-- no video. We sometimes share screens also. Mostly my client shares his/hers, and sometimes the other way round. I rarely take control of my client’s screen when s/he does.

Some of my clients are recording our meetings for latter reference. 
So with this, they no longer have to take any notes, but just can turn the recording and go thru. The meetings are all technical-- it’s not about “who said what”, validating what’s been going on, etc. That just isn’t the nature of these meetings.

I’ve been ok all along with this and still am. But wondering still.

Should I be any concerned being recorded like this, can I end up with any trouble?

UPDATE:

This isn't for a company-- I'm a freelancer.

I don't always sign an agreement-- some jobs are small. When I sign, there hasn't been anything about this-- recording/not in the contract.

UPDATE-2:

Can I ask them not to record me? Sometimes I've been recorded without being asked.

Comment: You could ask to record the meeting yourself, that way you both have the exact same record of the conversation.

Answer (score 4):

Some things to consider:

1. **Are you saying things that could be taken out of context?**
2. **Are you relaying any private info?**
3. **Are you discussing options which could be interpreted as agreements?**
4. **What does corporate info security say?**

Answer (score 1):

> Can I ask them not to record me? Sometimes I've been recorded without
>   being asked.

Certainly you can ask not to be recorded.

And if they insist, you can choose not to work with them. Since you are a freelancer, you can decide on your own how your work interactions must proceed. You only need to be willing to walk away from a gig that won't interact the way you prefer.